# Riemann hypothesis and Einstein manifolds

Tags: number-theory, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

The Riemann hypothesis states that all non trivial zeroes of the Riemann zeta function lie on a straight line (in the complex plane) or on a circle (on the Riemann sphere) which can be mapped onto the considered straight line through stereographic projection. But the Riemann sphere and the Euclidean plane are also Einstein manifolds of dimension $2$, the first with Einstein constant  $ k=1 $, the second with  $ k=0 $ hence Ricci flat.

I would like to know if there is an interpretation of the Riemann hypothesis in terms of general relativity, and if yes, which.

Edit: Also, have cosmological models where the value of the cosmological constant equals the one of the de Bruijn-Newman constant been considered?

Comment: Maybe such an interpretation could be the trajectory of a free particle, with the center of the "Riemann circle" acting like a mass of spherical symmetry in the case  $ k=1 $ .

Comment: There is at least a first encounter https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.03720.pdf .

Comment: Sylvain Julien : If you interpret it not as a free particle in terms of spherical symmetry (and therefore linked to classical relativism) but as the quantity of reactions a particle can have crossing it's momentum (of spherical symmetry) you're getting much closer to the subscription of a surface geometrically written by the Null space of a L-function like Riemann's.